# Electron in a classical orbit

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons

In a laboratory we create a positive charge $Q$ at the origin. We then release an electron at a distance $R$, much larger than the Bohr radius. Its velocity $v$ is perpendicular to its position, and the magnitude is chosen such that the centripetal force is equal to the electrostatic force. Therefore the electron starts to move in a classical circular orbit around the origin.

As it moves in its orbit, the electron is accelerated and hence emits photons (Bremsstrahlung). Due to this loss of energy of the system, the electron begins to spiral inwards. At some stage, a transition must take place from its classical (circular or spiral) motion to quantum-mechanical behaviour, in which the position and momentum are no longer sharp and well-defined, but instead described by a probability density based on a wavefunction. Of particular interest is that the original motion was $2D$ but it now evolves to become $3D$. Is this transition generated by the emission of Bremsstrahlung, or are there are other (quantum-mechanical) processes at work ? Has this phenomenon been studied and observed ?

Comment: actually, it emits synchrotron radiation...which is names because electrons travel in near circular orbits in a synchrotron.

Answer (score 1):

> in which the position and momentum are no longer sharp and
> well-defined

Its position and momentum are never sharp and well defined. The picture of an elementary particle as an electron in a defined circular trajectory is not possible according to QM.

What can be said is that the initial orbital is not the ground state of the system, and photons are released until a stable stationary state is reached.

Comment: In Bohm's interpretation the electron has a defined trajectory, so this is certainly possible in QM. In fact, QM says nothing about what an electron is and what it is doing, it just gives you a formula to calculate the results of some experiments, that's all. If you look at how the energy levels and orbitals are calculated you actually assume that the electron is a point particle that obeys classical physics (Coulomb law and Newton's laws) and, based on those assumptions you calculate the Hamiltonian. Only then you use that Hamiltonian in Schrodinger's equation.

Comment: It is therefore quite bizarre to claim that what you assumed in the first part of the calculation is false. Sure, logically it is possible, since false assumptions can lead to truth, but you still need to explain why this classical/wrong calculation leads you to the correct Hamiltonian in the end.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, basic article about [Bremsstrahlung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremsstrahlung) has all required links to related phenomena. I.e. :

> while free–bound radiation refers to the radiative combination process, in which a free electron [recombines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_recombination) with an ion

So to put it shortly,- when due to Bremsstrahlung (free-free) radiation electron looses kinetic energy until amount left is less than ionization energy of "to be formed" neutral atom, i.e. when $ K_e < \mathcal{E}_{ion}$, then plasma ion captures electron and binds it to the local system into 3D mode.

There is a substantial research papers about radiative recombination in plasma, you can check it in [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.lt/scholar?hl=lt&as_sdt=0%2C5&as_vis=1&q=%22radiative+recombination%22+plasma). You will find many interesting papers, like this one "[Collisional-radiative recombination in cold plasmas](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.12.1246)", J. Stevefelt, J. Boulmer, and J -F. Delpech
Phys. Rev. A 12, 1246 – Published 1 October **1975**.